# Tokken Holding on coinbooks.io

Tags: etherscan

I put my private key on etherscan.io and retrive my public adress and put it on coinbooks.io for watch.

In the token holdings i see an another adress with a high value of tokkens.

haw can i understand this.are this my tokkens ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should never reveal your private key to the public under any circumstances. I would advise you to create new public/private key pair and transfer all your tokens there.

To answer your question, you should search by your public address on etherscan.io
And then refer to the section that looks like this:
[image]

This should have a list of all the tokens you own.